# Using Ionic DevApp to see app running on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to run an Ionic app on a VirtualBox machine.

I'm trying to use the [DevApp](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/) to see the application, but it does not work when the app is running inside the VM, but it does work when it is running outside.

Basically what the DevApp do is scan the network for machines serving the application. But since it is running inside a VM it has a totally different IP, like it is in another network.

Is it possible to see my app inside my VM? How?